# jQuery: how to include validation in the ajaxForm function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ajaxform

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381768/ajaxform-not-working-inside-the-validation-submithandler)  has been asked, but the answer wasn't confirmed. I tried it but it didn't work. So I would like to ask the same question again (Is this appropriate? If not, please advise me what to do).

I have a form which needs to be validates and then submitted with ajaxForm (the form contains image and file data, so submission with `.serialize()` won't work). The following are the details:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="..." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
  <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
  <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
  ...
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myForm").ajaxForm ({

    beforeSubmit: function() {
      $("#myForm").validate({
        onkeyup:false,
        rules: {
          ...
        },
        messages: {
          ...
        },
      });
    },

    success: function(returnData) {
      $('#content').html(returnData);
    }

  });

});
```

The `ajaxForm` part is OK. But the form is simply submitted without validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.validate()` is used for initializing the plugin on DOM ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), so pull that outside of the other function.

*Initialize* the two plugins within DOM ready, and then utilize any appropriate built-in callback functions...

- Use the [`beforeSubmit` callback function of the `ajaxForm` plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object) to programmatically check the form's validity using the [Validate plugin's `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).

**You will not need to worry about creating any new `submit` handler or `click` handler functions since both plugins already capture the `submit` event automatically.**

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/MF26D/**

Rearrange your code into something more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm").validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // any other options,
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            //...
        },
        messages: {
            //...
        }
    });

    $("#myForm").ajaxForm({ // initialize the plugin
        // any other options,
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            return $("#myForm").valid(); // TRUE when form is valid, FALSE will cancel submit
        },
        success: function (returnData) {
            $('#content').html(returnData);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Wow! The code works immediately. Thanks a million, Sparky. You saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#myForm").ajaxForm ({

        beforeSubmit: function() {
           if (!$("#myform").valid())
                    return;
        },

        success: function(returnData) {
          $('#content').html(returnData);
        }

      });

    });
```

Comment: This seems very similar to the original solution. How do I arrange the `.valid()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Can call the form plugin within a submit handler:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventaDefault();

   var isValid=/* run your validation code that determines true or false*/

   if( isValid){
     $(this).ajaxForm({/* plugin options*/})
  }

})
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with jQuery. How do I set the value of the variable `isValid` by `validation()` function? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a plugin to validate? If so , what plugin ( provide link to docs).

Comment: I think you're missing a `(function` next to `.submit`.

Comment: I'm using jzaefferer's plugin: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.

Comment: try using `ajaxSubmit` within validate `submitHandler` callback. See example in validate plugin docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions Have never had problems using `submitHandler`